# Java GC log is not obvious about major and full GC - Serial Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I examine Java GC logs but there is something strange about GC types. My test application runs on Java 8u121 x64 with these JVM command line GC options:

```
-XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

There is a snippet from GC log:

```
2017-09-05T22:16:44.677+0200: 1.581: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-09-05T22:16:44.678+0200: 1.581: [DefNew: 139765K->17429K(157248K), 0.0936400 secs] 362075K->361613K(506816K), 0.0937556 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.02, real=0.09 secs] 
2017-09-05T22:16:45.177+0200: 2.081: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-09-05T22:16:45.177+0200: 2.081: [DefNew: 157184K->157184K(157248K), 0.0000394 secs]2017-09-05T22:16:45.177+0200: 2.081: [Tenured: 344183K->349561K(349568K), 0.0605620 secs] 501368K->500745K(506816K), [Metaspace: 2831K->2831K(1056768K)], 0.0607333 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2017-09-05T22:16:45.239+0200: 2.142: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-09-05T22:16:45.239+0200: 2.142: [Tenured: 349561K->349547K(349568K), 0.0450676 secs] 506685K->506671K(506816K), [Metaspace: 2831K->2831K(1056768K)], 0.0451294 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

As you can see the first line obviously a minor GC with DefNew collector.
I found an article about GC logs [here](https://plumbr.eu/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations).
Based on that the second line is a full GC. It seemed right because it collects young and old generation and even Metaspace too. But what happened in the third line? This log entry said it was a full GC. But it collected only the old generation. It seems the log entries are wrong: the second was a full gc and the third was a major gc.

So the question is: **why the "full GC" title in the 3rd line?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is actually part of the collection reported on the third line. If you used `-XX:+PrintGC` this would be reported as Full GC only.

The gc logging will be unified in JDK9 - see e.g. [this comparison](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~brutisso/JEP-271/pre-review.00/compare.html), which explains these logging st